# What's this odd kind of battery group size all about?

Tags: battery

Car is a 2000 New Beetle aspirated.  I am trying to figure out the battery group size.

Auto parts store website "parts lookup" features tend to feature batteries that show a group size of 47, which sounds like a normal [BCI group size](https://www.jegs.com/Sizecharts/bcigroup.html) to me, generally they are 2-digit numbers over 20.

However [some websites](https://www.autobatteries.com/en-us/car-battery-finder?year=2000&make=Volkswagen&model=Beetle&engine=L4-2.0L&find=find) keep giving me a group size of "H5". That's not even a *number format* of group size I am used to hearing.

What's the deal with this new type of group size?  Is this just an equivalent, or is this size different in some way that I need to care about?

Comment: Is the "H5" a size format given by one particular brand?

Comment: @SolarMike no, I've seen it from several sources.

Comment: Sources as websites or resellers or the battery manufacturers?

Comment: @SolarMike i linked one example.  mainly I am checking websites of  auto parts stores, some of them are secretive about group size.  But this "H5" thing keeps coming up.  What's the difference between H5 and Group 47?

Comment: well, S6 or S5 is shown by Bosch : https://www.boschautoparts.com/en/auto

Comment: Might want to offer a bounty on this.  I have the same question.  It's all really confusing, especially when I hear forums talking about using a totally different group than what the OEM was.  Based on things I read, it seemed like there were more differences between groups than just dimensions.